# how to re-use a composite UserControl inside another region in cal(prism) framework?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, cal

I'm using CAL framework in my application and I came to a point where I needed to re-use my composite UserControl somewhere else, i.e. would create a new instance of that usercontrol for the next region and change some of it's properties as per the UIContext.

When I tried to do so, I got an exception that it's children have already been registered.

Any sample-code in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: `tried to do so` requires a code sample

Comment: Do you want me to post a sample code for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a glitch. CAL is not that flexible to re-use composite usercontrols. I had to finally create a base UI and then derrived two different composite usercontrol classes from it.